# How to set a variable based on bootstrap item selection

Tags: javascript, calculator, bootstrap-modal

So I'm trying to set the variable w (for wattage) based on which LED module the user selects. I'm using the bootstrap library.

Here's what's inside the body tags:

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>LED Power Supply Calculator</h2>
  <p>Please select your LED type, then type how many LEDs you will be using in your box</p>                                        
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">Select your LED
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
      <li class="dropdown-header">Wide angle beam</li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="javascript: onclick(w = 1.2);">HLC3S - HW W65K</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="javascript: onclick(w = 0.72);">HLC3S - LW W65K</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
      <li class="dropdown-header">Standard beam</li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="javascript: onclick(w = 0.06);">HLC3S XD W65K</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<BR>
<form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="usr">How many LEDs</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="usr">
    </div>
</div>

 <script type="text/javascript">    
      document.write(w * 10);   
 </script>
```

I want to eventually multiply the wattage by the number of LEDs the user puts in. Right now I just need help setting the variable 'w' when the user clicks an LED type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do a document.write all your content will be wiped out instead here we defined a function `w()` whick takes in the value of watt and does your calculation and prints it in the span added in html `<span class="form-control" id="watt">`

Hope this helps

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>LED Power Supply Calculator</h2>
  <p>Please select your LED type, then type how many LEDs you will be using in your box</p>                                        
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">Select your LED
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
      <li class="dropdown-header">Wide angle beam</li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" onclick="w(1.2);">HLC3S - HW W65K</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" onclick="w(0.72);">HLC3S - LW W65K</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
      <li class="dropdown-header">Standard beam</li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" onclick="w(0.06);">HLC3S XD W65K</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<BR>
<form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="usr">How many LEDs</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="usr">
      <span class="form-control" id="watt"></span>
    </div>
</div>

 <script type="text/javascript">    
    function w(val){
        document.getElementById('watt').innerHTML = val*10;
    }      

    //document.write(w * 10);   
 </script>
```